# How do I restore sddm after corrupted update?

Tags: nvidia, 15.04, kubuntu, display-manager

A week ago I had a power failure in the middle of an upgrade.  System now has um ... "issues."  Below are the configuration, status, symptoms, etc.  Please help however you can.

System:  kubuntu 15.04, kernel ...-30, 16gb ram, UEFI boot (dual boot, still win 8) with grub, dual nvidia 970 for video and sound to a 4k monitor.

Symptoms:
Originally it was hosed. I reinstalled linux-generic to get it to wake up.  It threw lots of "failed to load kernel module" and a reinstall of systemd took care of that.  Worked my way through the boot log messages so that now it comes up in single-user mode fine.

But sddm dies.  It tries to come up, but throws segmentation error (11).

The log messages are:

```
sddm.log--
   * Unrecognized OpenGL Version
   * Cannot create children for parents of a different thread
   * org.freedescktop.Udisk2 had owner ''

kern.log--
   * ... not configured to drive a VGA console
```

Other errors:
Frequently get `Error Initializing Authority ... g-io-err-quark 1`.  By frequently, I mean when running commands like `systemctl` or `reboot`.

I tried several things that have been suggested here, and none of them have affected the startx problem:

- start over with a boot disk (got the infamous "wubi" problem, and figured I was better off working with what I had)
- fix fstab  (cleaned up boot log)
- update QT
- update Mesa
- re-install nvidia-346
- update policykit-1
- update apport
- manually start sddm (no effect)
- install lightdm (starts x but won't log me on)
- install xdm (won't bring up any usable window-forced reboot)

None of that has made any difference.  Sddm still fails and I still get the above-listed errors.

Throwing myself at your mercy.  What am I missing?  What to try next?

Comment: I know you're trying to fix it, but at this point, why not backup your /home directory and do a fresh install? To me, it sounds like something's been corrupted to the point that no quick-fix will repair - like fragments of undeleted data, or a fragmented kernel. I'm sorry I cannot be of more use, but a power failure isn't the best thing to try to fix - it will never be the same if you can get it to function again without a clean install.

Comment: I have little else left.  :-)

Someone please point me to the best instructions for getting past the dreaded "wubi does not support EFI" issues that keep my disk from booting.

Comment: Am about to follow the instructions here:  https://journalxtra.com/linux/desktop-recovery/the-definitive-guide-to-getting-your-linux-desktop-back/ and will report back.  If it fails, there's always the "press F6 - esc, modify" to get to the repair screen.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it over the weekend.  Lots of medium-sized issues, and (if you read that far) a *theory* as to the cause.

1. Tried update from 15.04 install disk.  It died in the same way.
2. Did fresh install (over formatted disk) from 15.04.  It died the same
   way.
3. Did fresh install from 15.10 disk.  It hung up in the middle.
4. Brought in a linux admin friend.  He found the 3-year old "you MUST" click the format button on / or the installer hangs" information.  After that it installed fine, including SDDM start, running X, etc.

Currently the system is up and restoring from backup.  It shows that its using nouveau drivers, not nvidia drivers.  I'm not touching it.  It's adequate for now.  The issue was most likely some combination of corruption and crazy version mismatch between nvidia and mesa.